# Order by relationship deep

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is my models structure:

```
class Family extends Eloquent
{
    public function members()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Person');
    }   
}

class Person extends Eloquent
{
    public function family()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Family');
    }

    public function school()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
    }
}

class School extends Eloquent
{
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Person');
    }
}
```

So, a `Person` belongs to both `Family` and `School`.

I fetch a Family:

```
$family = Family::find(1);
```

And list the members:

```
foreach ($family->members AS $member) {
    $member->name;
    foreach ($member->school AS $school) {
        $school->name;
    }
}
```

How can I order the schools by `name` in ASC order?

### EDIT

How to make this list ordered:

```
foreach ($family->members AS $member) {
    $member->school->name;
}
```

### EDIT 2

Very sorry. I've got mixed up.

What I'm trying to achieve is to sort the members of the family by the name of the school that they're attending.

A Person can attend only one school.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$family = Family::with(['members.school'=>function($q){
    $q->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
}])->find(1);
```

The **`with`** function will eagerload your records preventing the N + 1 query problem and also make your application run faster.

```
foreach ($family->members AS $member) {
   $member->name;
   foreach ($member->school AS $school) {
     $school->name;
   }
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Would you need to say `members.school` in the first argument on the with, as he wants to order by school name, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to eager load the relationship then order the relationship:

```
$family = Family::with(['members.school'  => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
}])->find(1);
```

**Edit**

In response to your comment:

> What if every person belongs to only one school, and I want to list
>   members ordered by the school name, without the second loop? Will
>   update question with the code in a second

I'm pretty sure you can go ahead and use the same query above with the eager loading as the `school()` relation on `Person` is `belongsTo` so it will return one eloquent record not many. You'd only need another for loop if it was returning an eloquent collection. So you should be able to run the loop like so:

```
foreach ($family->members AS $member) {
    $member->name;
    $member->school->name;
}
```

Unless I'm missing something?

I'll just point out as well that if you always want them sorted by name, you can define a relation on your `Person` object for school and order it like this:

```
public function schoolOrderedByName() // you could just call it school()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\School')->orderBy('name', 'asc');
}
```

Then you don't have to write the constraint every time you use the relation:

```
$family = Family::with(members.schoolOrderedByName')->find(1);
```

Comment: Ok. What if every person belongs to only one school, and I want to list members ordered by the school name, without the second loop? Will update question with the code in a second

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the members don't get ordered. Trying to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: That's because you asked to order by school name, not members so that's the answers you got from me and others. Update your question if you're trying to order by members also. Thanks.

Comment: Very sorry, got really mixed up. Updated the question. Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Really sorry but I'm a bit confused even after the update on your question. Perhaps you could try writing out an example of some dummy data in your question of how the data should look like or hopefully somebody else can help out!

Comment: hey, sorry about that whole mess. I've posted a new question where it's all laid out in a better fashion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922799/laravel-ordering-a-model-belongsto

Answer (score 0):

Before the second `foreach`, add this statement

`$schools = $member->school->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();`

Like this

```
foreach ($family->members AS $member) {
    $member->name;
    $schools = $member->school->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
    foreach ($schools AS $school) {
        $school->name;
    }
}
```