# Laravel ordering a model belongsTo

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is my models structure:

```
class Family extends Model
{
    public function members()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Person');
    }   
}

class Person extends Model
{
    public function family()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Family');
    }

    public function school()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
    }
}

class School extends Model
{
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Person');
    }
}
```

In short, a `Person` belongs to many `Schools`, but only one `Family`.

Dummy data:

```
families_table

id | name
---------
1  | Smith
2  | Doe

people_table

id | family_id | school_id | name
----------------------------------
1  | 1         | 1         | Betty
2  | 2         | 1         | John

school_table

id | name
-------------
1  | MIT
```

So we have to users: `Smith, Betty` and `Doe, John`. Now, if I do this:

```
$school = School::find(1);

foreach ($school->students AS $student) {
    echo $student->family->name . ', ' . $student->name
}
```

I will get:

```
Smith, Betty
Doe, John
```

What I want to see is:

```
Doe, John
Smith, Betty
```

How do I get the `School` and list the `members` sorted by the `name` field in from the `Family` table?

Comment: If anyone has an idea for a better title, I'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is by sorting collection:

```
$school->students->load('family');
$school->students->sortBy(function ($item) {
    return $item->family->name;
});
```

You can also sort results in query using join like:

```
$students = $school->students()
    ->with('family')
    ->select('students.*')
    ->join('families', 'families.id' , '=', 'students.family_id')
    ->orderBy('families.name')
    ->get();
$school->setRelation('students', $students);
```